# Initialize Self.NaviationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a tab-based application. In `SecondViewController`, there is a `UITableView` with several cells. When you swipe on a cell, you are sent to another view controller, `speciesController`. The below code works to send the app to another view, and it does set up a navigation bar, but there is no back button.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SpeciesViewController* speciesController = [[SpeciesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SpeciesViewController" bundle:nil];


    Species *theSpecies = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    speciesController.theSpecies = theSpecies;

    switch (sortBySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case kSortByCommonNameFirst:
            speciesController.title = [theSpecies commonNameFirstLast];
            break;
        case kSortByCommonNameLast:
            speciesController.title = [theSpecies commonNameLastFirst];
            break;
        case kSortByScientificName:
            speciesController.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                                       [theSpecies.scientificName substringToIndex:1],
                                       [[theSpecies.scientificName substringFromIndex:1] lowercaseString]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    speciesController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    //self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    //// Store current index path for viewDidAppear animation. ////
    self->currentSelectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:speciesController];
    navBar.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    [self presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I realize that to have a backbutton, you need to push the current view onto the navigation controller stack. However, changing

```
navBar.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[self presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:navBar animated:NO];
```

Doesn't work. In fact, the app fails to change to a different view, and I believe this is because there is no `self.navigationController`

I tried to add/initialize one with this line:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];
```

but that caused the application to crash.

I appreciate any information about adding a navigation controller to an app (in storyboard or programatically). I'm afraid most of the examples I saw were outdated, from 2011 or so with methods like `self.window addSubview...`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having `SecondViewController` as a Tab Item, set that Tab Item to a Navigation Controller with `SecondViewController` as its Root VC.

Then, on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, all you have to do is:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: speciesController animated:YES];
```

The "back button" will automatically be there.

Answer (score 0):

after

```
  UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:speciesController];
```

try

```
speciesController.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]; 
if (self.navigationController)
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:navBar animated:NO];
else 
   [self presentViewController: navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller `